# what causes this error: Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
    IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.SQLPendingEventRecord> dataset1 = _v3Context.SQLPendingEvents
                     .Where(sp => sp.EventType.ToString() == str100w && sp.EventDateTime > dtStartDate && !sp.KeyDeviceID.ToString().Contains('~'))
                     .AsEnumerable() // further processing occurs on client
                     .Select((sp, index) => new DataAccessLayer.SQLPendingEventRecord
                     {
                         ID = index + 1,
                         KeyDeviceID=sp.KeyDeviceID,
                         UpdateTime=sp.UpdateTime,
                         EventClass=sp.EventClass,
                         EventCode=sp.EventCode,
                         EventType=sp.EventType,
                         EventDateTime=Convert.ToDateTime(sp.EventDateTime),
                         KeyPropertyID=Convert.ToInt32 (sp.KeyPropertyID),
                         KeyEntityID=Convert.ToInt32 (sp.KeyEntityID),
                         EventText=sp.EventText,
                         KeyUserID=sp.KeyUserID,
                         //sp.EventImage,
                         TaskType=sp.TaskType,
                         TaskSubType=sp.TaskSubType,
                         UniqueTaskID=sp.UniqueTaskID
                     }).ToList();
```

I have just added:  && !sp.KeyDeviceID.ToString().Contains('~'))
Now, I get odd error msg: Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'.
Before that, I had no problem.
Now, I get this cryptic error message.
I need to put this all in one query, due to the size of the database.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps there's no SQL equivalent for `Contains()` for the provider you are using.

Comment: What is the type of `KeyDeviceId`?

Comment: This line works fine: dataset1 = dataset1.Where(sp => !sp.KeyDeviceID.ToString().Contains('~')).ToList();

Comment: KeyDeviceId is a string.

Comment: So why are you calling `ToString` on it?

Comment: @SteveStaple: That line would work because you're then calling `Where` using LINQ to Objects - no SQL translation is required.

Comment: How do you know it is Linq to Objects?

Comment: @jle: Because of the type of `dataset1`. If Steve is using `dataset1 = dataset1.Where(...)` then that will be calling `Enumerable.Where`.

Comment: Makes sense.  In that case, switching to string literal should work

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that it's using `Enumerable.Contains(string, char)` (because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`) whereas you really want [`string.Contains(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Just changing it to:

```
!sp.KeyDeviceID.ToString().Contains("~")
```

*may* fix the issue.

Note that if `KeyDeviceID` is already a string property, I'd get rid of the `ToString()` call:

```
!sp.KeyDeviceID.Contains("~")
```

Comment: @SteveStaple: I doubt that that would give the same error as with the `'~'` argument. (Did you spot that I'd changed the literal type?)

Comment: I got it to work, by putting "~" in a constant thus: string strTilde = "~"; IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.SQLPendingEventRecord> dataset1 = _v3Context.SQLPendingEvents
                         .Where(sp => sp.EventType.ToString() == str100w && sp.EventDateTime > dtStartDate && !sp.KeyDeviceID.Contains (strTilde))

Comment: @SteveStaple: By doing what? (Bear in mind that Stack Overflow isn't meant to just help you - it's meant to help other people with the same problem later.)

Comment: Jon Skeet - Enter button saved my message before I was ready. No newline!

Comment: @SteveStaple: That sounds very fishy - are you absolutely *certain* it was failing when you used a string literal? You weren't perhaps still running the code with the character literal instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linq to SQL?  Linq to SQL does not support all of the .Net functionality for data types.  You can use SQLFunctions to replicate some of the functionality.  If sp.KeyDeviceID is not a string, then using ToString() would throw an error if you are using Linq to SQL.
Try

```
IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.SQLPendingEventRecord> dataset1 = _v3Context.SQLPendingEvents
                     .Where(sp => sp.EventType.ToString() == str100w && sp.EventDateTime > dtStartDate && !**SQLFunctions.CharIndex(sp.KeyDeviceID,"~")>0)**
                     .AsEnumerable() // further processing occurs on client
                     .Select((sp, index) => new DataAccessLayer.SQLPendingEventRecord
                     {
                         ID = index + 1,
                         KeyDeviceID=sp.KeyDeviceID,
                         UpdateTime=sp.UpdateTime,
                         EventClass=sp.EventClass,
                         EventCode=sp.EventCode,
                         EventType=sp.EventType,
                         EventDateTime=Convert.ToDateTime(sp.EventDateTime),
                         KeyPropertyID=Convert.ToInt32 (sp.KeyPropertyID),
                         KeyEntityID=Convert.ToInt32 (sp.KeyEntityID),
                         EventText=sp.EventText,
                         KeyUserID=sp.KeyUserID,
                         //sp.EventImage,
                         TaskType=sp.TaskType,
                         TaskSubType=sp.TaskSubType,
                         UniqueTaskID=sp.UniqueTaskID
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Question has new been answered.